# How to incrementally deploy to Amazon Beanstalk from Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my Maven Web Application (with Spring MVC) project to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk through the Amazon SDK plugin for Eclipse.

This works fine. The problem is every time I make a new change to the code, I try to deploy using "Incremental Deployment" option.

Although everything goes fine, when I try to open the app, i find that the earliest version of the code gets deployed. So I have to deploy the whole app everytime.

What's wrong? Am I doing something wrong. Please guide me.

Comment: Did you tried to deploy your application withe help,of aws.push instead of Eclipse?

Comment: @Vadim911, I haven't tried that. How to do that?

Comment: Article here: http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/06/aws-elastic-beanstalk-simplfied-command-line-eb.html . I would like to add, that described aproach works for java too. If you need additional help let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the handy tutorial. Will read it and let you know if it works. But I'm maintaining a Mercurial repo, will it work with Hg too?

Comment: Nope. As I understood git in this case just a tool for deployment. Just create empty git repository. Then run eb init. When you need to deploy your application put your war file into git folder and do git commit. Then git aws.push. After this your application will be deployed on EB.